# PHP says Undefined even when it is clearly defined in AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on some function which needs to call php using ajax and get some values. How ever I'll post my JS function **part** below.

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'php/getAccountJobs.php',
        ContentType:"application/json",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{email:$.cookie("email")},
        success : function(arr)
        {
            for(var i=0 ; i<parseInt(response); i++) // number of jobs are the response we use there
            {
                var jobmsg = arr[2*i] ; 
                var imgurl = arr[2*i+1]; 
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "php/addDivAccountJobs.php",
                        dataType:'json',
                        data: {imgURL:imgurl,message:jobmsg},
                        }).done(function( html ){ alert(html);});
            }
        }
        });
```

So I checked the console log and saw this following error.

```
Notice: Undefined index:imgURL
```

So what I thought was to use isset function to test whether imgURL value is being set or not.

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["imgURL"]) && isset($_POST["message"]))
{
    $username = $_SESSION["firstname"]." ".$_SESSION["lastname"];
    $imgurl = $_POST["imgURL"];
    $msg = $_POST["message"];
    $fullecho = '<div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="profile-card text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive"src="'.$imgurl.'">
                        <div class="profile-info">
                          <h2 class="hvr-underline-from-center" id="jobOwnerName">'.$username.'</h2>
                          <div id="jobMessage">'.$msg.'.</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>';
    echo json_encode($fullecho);
    die();
}
else
    echo json_encode("error");
?>
```

As I expected what I received was error message in alert box.

**My Problem**

I went through every stackexchange question and tried to find the reason behind it and fix it. but none of those solutions gave me a proper answer. Please can someone help me to find the problem?

Comment: @farhadamjady Oh yeah.Now I tried to see what output comes by this. and I found a undefined value. Can you post it as an answer? it would help to another person.

Comment: I would try to make 1 call and get 1 response.  Nested calls to the same server seem unnecessary.

Comment: @sam1234 ofcourse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your json property has undefined value its completely disapear from json. so it because arr[2*i] or arr[2*i+1] somewhere get undefined value in the loop